# Unable to copy data from one database table row to another database

Tags: php

I am trying to copy customer data from one database to another and I can get the script to make the new row on the second database but the row is blank and not carrying the information  over.

Example - I have a customer on the contacts table with ID 242 and want to move their details to the new database (both with same table structure) and pressing a button on the customers profile page.

The script runs fine and does not produce any error messages and a vardump shows that it passes the customer ID over fine but any of the other row information. $name shows as null.

Current URL `.php?id=<?=$_GET['id']?`

I have worked out that I can send the information over using `.php?name=<?=$contact['name']?>` and changing the variable to `$_GET['name']` which writes the information to the table fine but is very insecure.

So in a nut shell, the current code (below) just creates a new table row that is blank.

I have no more error messages to work from and PHP error reporting and ERRMODE_EXCEPTION are both switched on.

Code

```
<?php
session_start();
define('db_host','localhost');
// database username
define('db_user','user');
// database password
define('db_pass','');
// database name
define('db_name','newdatabase');
// database charset - change this only if utf8 is unsupported by your language
define('db_charset','utf8');

// var_dump($data->status);
// exit();

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . db_host . ';dbname=' . db_name . ';charset=' . db_charset, db_user, db_pass);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $data = json_decode($_POST['array'], TRUE);


//$id = isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] != 'auto' ? $_GET['id'] : NULL;
//$name             =       $data->name;
$name             =       $_GET['name'];
$name       =     $data->name;
$email      =     $data->email;
$phone      =     $data->phone;
$title      =     $data->title;
$created        =     $data->created;
$status         =     $data->status;
$riskdv         =     $data->riskdv;
$nin            =     $data->nin;
$dob            =     $data->dob;
$nextofkin      =     $data->nextofkin;
$address        =     $data->address;
$refname        =     $data->refname;
$refagency      =     $data->refagency;
$refadd         =     $data->refadd;
$refemail       =     $data->refemail;
$refnum         =     $data->refnum;
$riskvoi        =     $data->riskvoi;
$riskar         =     $data->riskar;
$risksat        =     $data->risksat;
$riskpph        =     $data->riskpph;
$riskpmh        =     $data->riskpmh;
$refpos         =     $data->riskpos;
$mentalhealth   =     $data->mentalheath;
$hisdrug        =     $data->hisdrug;
$exoff      =     $data->exoff;
$learndif       =     $data->learndif;
$hisalc         =     $data->hisalc;
$fled       =     $data->fled;
$rousl      =     $data->rousl;
$trave      =     $data->trave;
$yplc       =     $data->yplc;
$psdpsd     =     $data->psd; 
$hivaids        =     $data->hivadids;
$hep            =     $data->hep;
$phyneeds       =     $data->phyneeds;
$mentneeds      =     $data->mentneeds;
$meds       =     $data->meds;
$subdose        =     $data->subdose;
$methmil        =     $data->methmil;
$alcdepend      =     $data->alcdepend;
$ivdrug         =     $data->ivdrug;
$onmeth         =     $data->onmeth;
$compdetox      =     $data->compdetox;
$drugdepend     =     $data->drugdepend;
$dip            =     $data->dip;
$attcdp     =     $data->attcdp;
$heroin         =     $data->heroin;
$canna      =     $data->canna;
$meth       =     $data->meth;
$coc            =     $data->coc;
$crack      =     $data->crack;
$solvents       =     $data->solvents;
$amph       =     $data->amph;
$spice      =     $data->spice;
$premed         =     $data->premed;
$halluc         =     $data->halluc;
$subu       =     $data->subu;
$alclevel       =     $data->alchevel;
$otherinfo      =     $data->otherinfo;
$btype      =     $data->btype;
$bamount        =     $data->bamount;
$bstartdate     =     $data->bstartdate;
$bnextpay       =     $data->bnextpay;
$padd1      =     $data->padd1;
$padd2      =     $data->padd2;
$preoff         =     $data->preoff;
$pendcase       =     $data->pendcase; 
$precon     =     $data->precon; 
$onprob         =     $data->onprob;
$shop       =     $data->shop;
$cook       =     $data->cook;
$money      =     $data->money;
$cleaning       =     $data->cleaning;
$perh       =     $data->perh;
$housing_benefit_claim_date         =     $data->housing_benefit_claim_date;
$housing_benefit_reference      =     $data->housing_benefit_reference; 
$housing_benefit_cancelled      =     $data->housing_benefit_cancelled; 
$date_left_left         =     $data->date_left_left;
$number_of_times_at_reflections         =     $data->number_of_times_at_reflections;
$amount_of_service_charge_owed      =     $data->amount_of_service_charge_owed;
$reason_for_leaving         =     $data->reason_for_leaving;
$home_town      =     $data->home_town;
$town_moved_to  =     $data->town_moved_to;
$image      =     $data->image; 
$is_moved_in    =     $data->is_moved_in; 
$datemovedin    =     $data->datemovedin;
$gp_surgery     =     $data->gpsurgery; 
$rflfull        =     $data->rflfull;
$last_date_left     =     $data->last_date_left;
$med_cons       =     $data->med_cons;
$addinfo        =     $data->addinfo;
$compldetox     =     $data->compldetox;
$complprog      =     $data->complprog; 
$dietaryreq     =     $data->dietaryreq;


    // Update the record

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO contacts VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

$result = $stmt->execute([null, $name, $email, $phone, $title, $created, $status, $riskdv, $nin, $dob, $nextofkin, $address, $refname, $refagency, $refadd, $refemail, $refnum, $riskvoi, $riskar, $risksat, $riskpph, $riskpmh, $refpos, $mentalhealth, $hisdrug, $exoff, $learndif, $hisalc, $fled, $rousl, $trave, $yplc, $psd, $hivaids, $hep, $phyneeds, $mentneeds, $meds, $subdose, $methmil, $alcdepend, $ivdrug, $onmeth, $compdetox, $drugdepend, $dip, $attcdp, $heroin, $canna, $meth, $coc, $crack, $solvents, $amph, $spice, $premed, $halluc, $subu, $alclevel, $otherinfo, $btype, $bamount, $bstartdate, $bnextpay, $padd1, $padd2, $preoff, $pendcase, $precon, $onprob, $shop, $cook, $money, $cleaning, $perh, $housing_benefit_claim_date, $housing_benefit_reference, $housing_benefit_cancelled, $date_left_left, $number_of_times_at_reflections, $amount_of_service_charge_owed, $reason_for_leaving, $home_town, $town_moved_to, $image, $is_moved_in, $datemovedin, $gp_surgery, $rflfull, $last_date_left, $med_cons, $addinfo, $compldetox, $complprog, $dietaryreq]);

     echo "Entry added into Vader!";
var_dump($name);
     
?>
```

Comment: are you aware that your code is using a json coming from the POST request as the `array` parameter? and that you populate your insert statement with data coming from there? did you copy that code from somewhere else? did you do by yourself? what's your understanding of anything written there?

Comment: It was a script that someone wrote of me a while ago and trying to adapt it. I'm new(ish) to PHP.

Comment: there are several class of problems you need to address there: how to craft a sql insert to add a row to a db table; how to collect the data needed to insert this new row; how the user interface is supposed to be involved in this game; ... so to make it short I would suggest you to jsut drop the user interface stuff and the input/output in general. Just make a php code that prepare a sql statement as an INSERT with static parameters and that correctly performs. You'll find plenty of examples also here on SO. But this question can't be answered as is